# Center prompt window of window.onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, dom-events

How do I center the prompt of the `window.onbeforeunload` event. What do I need to add on my script in order for the prompt to show in the middle of the screen?

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">

          window.onbeforeunload = function() {
          return ""; 
          };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, that is not customizable.

> I mean what all you can change there is the **prompt messsage** of the prompt. Otherwise you can not change the UI of the prompt, and you can not perform any other action on choosing the options there...
>
> Everything in there like popup UI, button names will be changed according to browser.